Improved memory leads to writing success
I'm looking for a short story probably from  the 1950s or 60s (I probably read it on Project Gutenberg). I think the person telling the story is a TV producer. He gets a script from a newcomer, which is terrific and a huge success. The newcomer comes back sometime later, with a movie script that's even better. I think there's a novel in the story too - a novel that is universally recognized as the greatest ever.
It is revealed that the newcomer has invented a treatment that gives him a better memory of his own life, which allows him to better describe the inner life of characters. He plans on a final treatment that will give him total recall from birth - but something goes wrong (I don't remember what).

This sounds very much like a 1950s story, somehow. If a TV producer is a character, it could not be much earlier. I do not know why "better memory treatment" sounds 1950s, but it sure does. Maybe because it comes off to me as naive. Here's a guess: Von Vogt?

Could be Van Vogt. I'll look around

I kind of think it was a less famous guy - one of those prolific but mostly forgotten fellows from the fifties (Slesar? Pyfe?)

I mean Fyfe, not Pyfe

The Mind Digger by Winston Marks is a pretty good fit. It was published in Imagination Stories of Science and Fantasy in 1958. Here it is on Guntenberg.
The narrator produces stage plays rather than TV shows, but the rest is as you described:
"He gets a script from a newcomer"

"This - is - your first work?"
"My very first," he said,

"The newcomer comes back sometime later, with a movie script that's even better. I think there's a novel in the story too - a novel that is universally recognized as the greatest ever."

While I'm pondering this and negotiating with a Hollywood agent to maybe take Beach Boy off my hands, along comes Red Rice, an epic novel of Communist China that out-Bucked Pearl a hundred heart-wrenches to one.

"the newcomer has invented a treatment that gives him a better memory of his own life, which allows him to better describe the inner life of characters. He plans on a final treatment that will give him total recall from birth"

He brightened. "Would you believe it? I've contacted memories back to three months after my birth. At this rate I'll reach birth itself within a few weeks.

Later on, something does indeed go wrong.
I found this story using a trick I learned from another contributer here on Scifi: a search for "site:gutenberg.org improved memory script movie".

Thsnks - exactly right. I tried that search technique but I guess I didn't use the right words.
